# Directly read stream from uv4l server on external node.js server in network

Tags: node.js, webrtc, uv4l

I'm trying to connect the uv4l-server stream directly to a node.js server.

I'd like to be able to read the stream with the node-webrtc package on an external device. I already have a websocket connection between the two.

I know i can get a stream as an mjpeg by default but I need an actual webRTC stream so i can use it with the node-webrtc package.

What I'm trying to achieve in the end is to recreate the example at https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples/blob/master/examples/video-compositing but with a stream from the raspberry pi.

Hope this all makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

uv4l-server has a [webrtc extension](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/webrtc-extension/) - have you tried it? They list several webrtc tutorials on [their tutorial page](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/) too